# How Google public DNS gets the nameservers of my domain

Tags: dns

I can get my domain Hosting  Server IP  and nameservers from Google public DNS , I know Google can get the hosting server IP from domain's nameservers, but how Google gets the nameservers of my domain, only my domain registrar know my domain's nameservers, do Google public DNS (or any other public DNS) asks my domain registrar for the nameservers,

In other words how my domain's nameservers (which I provided only to my domain registrar) go public?

maybe it is very stupid question, but I couldn't find any answer on Google, I don't mind the down votes, but if you know pls provide me some reference of any hint for the answer, thanks

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I'm fairly sure this keeps getting downvoted because it's been asked and answered several times before – it's the core of "how does DNS work".

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I tried searching on Google but couldn't find any good explanation, could you please provide any link where I can get this information @grawity

Answer (score 2):

> only my domain registrar know my domain's nameservers

No. All registrars which sell domains from a given TLD must forward your domain's details to the *domain registry* which manages that TLD. (For example, the `com` top-level domain is managed by Verisign, the `horse` domain is managed by Nominet, etc.)

Usually registrars submit this information to the registry automatically via EPP or similar protocols. The domain only starts to "exist" after the registry is informed about it.

Once that's done, DNS resolvers can find it with a simple recursive search:

1. The resolver has a built-in list of nameservers for `.` ([the root](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers)).
2. The resolver asks one of the `.` nameservers about where `com` nameservers are.
3. The resolver asks one of the `com` nameservers about where `superuser.com` nameservers are.
4. The resolver asks one of the `superuser.com` nameservers for the website IP address.

Comment: oh, I get it, in simple words there are other upper level public databases  which stored the informations of each domain's nameservers, and each time I update my domain's nameservers at my registrar, my registrar must update nameservers details (of my domain)  at those upper level public databases... it was simpler than I thought many thanks :)